# Bootstrap 3 "media-left" class hides media instead

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

EDIT **It seems to look correctly in Firefox, but not in my Google Chrome**

I've come across a wierd problem. I have the latest Bootstrap CSS loaded, but media-left class hides the media element, whilst it all works fine with pull-left (which is deprecated)

Using bootstraps example code on for example, codepen.io, WORKS! But the same media example on my website does not work(except if I use pull-left). I've made sure the latest CSS is loaded, 3.3.5. I even deleted all local files.

And no, there's no other CSS overwriting .media-left

This is nagging me insanely, do anyone have a clue why standard bootstrap code doesn't work properly?
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media

This is the file im loading:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

I'm using the latest wordpress, in case you need to know that.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the website link?

Comment: Well ok, I had it locally(it's still in the making), but updated so you can see the problem here: http://www.gastagard.se/
Scroll down untill you see "PULL-LEFT" header.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7lg4p1 Both the media is shown here.

Comment: ok, wow, so that's a shock. I tried with Firefox because of that. And yes, it works there. Is this some render bug on Chrome perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it is a Chrome bug. Something to do with `display: table-cell`

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15067

Comment: I found it too, but since it is a really old thread, I thought they'd actually fix it. I guess I should still to pull-left meanwhile?
EDIT: But This have to be caused by SOMETHING, since I can see these bootstrap examples fine on their page.

Comment: Yes I guess so. Where does it say `pull-left` is deprecated? It is caused by the max-width on `.media-body`

Comment: It says directly under Bootstrap Media description.
Also, notice my edit in last comment.

Comment: please, do not include [bootstrap] as a tag. that's a program that boots the computer